# Moving the mouse pointer in C++ fails on Linux

Tags: c++, x11, mouse-cursor

I'm using the following code to hide and show the mouse cursor:

```
XDefineCursor( m_display, m_window, show ? None : m_hiddenCursor );  
XFlush( m_display );
```

That works fine. However, when I run this:

```
XWarpPointer( m_display, None, m_window, 0, 0, 0, 0, x, y );
XFlush( m_display );
```

The mouse doesn't move at all. Simply nothing happens. SetMousePos, which I'm using for Windows, works fine.

Comment: if you post a small compilable test case people can probably figure out the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while, but doesn't XWarpPointer make a *relative* move of the cursor using the passed offsets?  It looks like the passed offsets are (0,0) meaning that the cursor wouldn't move.  I think the routine you want to use is XMovePointer.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: According to the Xlib manual, that only happens if the destination window is None and there is no function with the name XMovePointer.

Comment: @Overv: sorry - as I said, it's been a while (about 15 years) since I had to monkey with X.  Good luck.